# Conflicting Gradle dependencies and vulnerabilities

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

There are different versions of this question out there, but I couldn't find one that answer my interrogation clearly.

Given a Gradle project with 2 dependencies, both of which depend on different versions of the same transitive dependency (and assuming that Gradle is *not* set to fail on version conflict).

In other words, the `./gradlew app:dependency` command would give an output that looks like :

```
+--- io.somelib:somelib-java:2.9.3
|    +--- com.somecommondep:common-dep-java:1.2.0
+--- com.otherlib:otherlib-java:5.8.2
|    +--- com.somecommondep:common-dep-java:1.1.0 -> 1.2.0
```

If version `1.1.0` of `com.somecommondep:common-dep-java` has a vulnerability (CVE-YYY-XXXXX ), scanners will flag the app as vulnerable.

However, my understanding is that:

- Only version `1.2.0` of `com.somecommondep:common-dep-java` will actually be used at runtime because the latest version of the transitive dependency is used by Gradle in this scenario
- The app is actually **not** vulnerable (false positive by the scanner)

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: This is answered by the Gradle documentation, specifically [Understanding dependency resolution](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html): _"Gradle will consider all requested versions, wherever they appear in the dependency graph. Out of these versions, it will select the highest one."_ (BTW: IMHO you're using a bad vulnerability scanning tool if it doesn't consider the actual dependency tree of your project)

Comment: Thank you. The vulnerability scanner is whatever google uses to scan your docker images in the artifact registry (which I have no control over, and no insight on, hence my interrogation).